# jQuery prepend tr after tr heading

Tags: html, jquery, sorting, prepend

I have the following HTML table.

```
<table id="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
        <td data-order="3">London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-order="1">Paris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
        <td data-order="2">Rome</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

London, Paris and Rome have a class named `show-on-top`. As the name suggests I want to move all `tr` with `show-on-top` on top of the table. I can do that with the following code.

```
$("#table tbody").prepend($('.show-on-top'));
```

But the problem is that London, Paris and Rome are shown before `<th>` (the "City" heading). Of course I want to place `show-on-top` rows on top of the table but **after heading** (first row). So I came up with the following idea.

```
$("#table tbody tr:eq(1)").prepend($('.show-on-top'));
```

I'm almost there. All my `show-on-top` are placed after heading but they're nested inside a `tr` like follows.

```
<table id="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tr class="show-on-top">
            <td data-order="3">London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="1">Paris</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="show-on-top">
            <td data-order="2">Rome</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I can't understand how the heck all my rows are nested inside a `tr`. I'm tried with hundreds of combinations of `parent`, `after`, `prepend`, `append` with no success.

**Bonus question**. `show-on-top` rows have `data-order` attribute that represents the order I want to sort th rows in question (Paris > Rome > London). I used `sort.data('order')` but nothing happens. I can't even see anything in `console.log()`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Consider putting your *heading* in a `<thead>`, not the `<tbody>`.  It would probably help with your issue, and be more semantically correct.

Comment: Your first solution would work if you use `.before()` instead of `.prepend()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `insertAfter()` and `:first` selector

```js
$(".show-on-top").insertAfter('#table tbody tr:first');
```

```css
.show-on-top{ color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="3">London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="1">Paris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="2">Rome</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's brillant. I was overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is move the heading rows out of `<tbody>` into `<thead>`

```js
$("#table tbody").prepend($('.show-on-top'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="3">London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="1">Paris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="2">Rome</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another solution is to use `.after()` to put the rows after the last row containing `th`.

```js
$("#table tbody tr:has(th):last").after($(".show-on-top"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="3">London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-order="1">Paris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show-on-top">
      <td data-order="2">Rome</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```